# Identify subsequent event windows (or occurrences) for each individual

Tags: stata

This question is in the context of `twoway line` with the `by()` option, but I think the bigger problem is how to identify a second (and all subsequent) event windows without a priori knowing every event window.

Below I generate some data with five countries over the 1990s and 2000s. In all countries an event occurs in 1995 and in Canada only the event repeats in 2005. I would like to plot `outcome` over the five years centered on each event in each country. If I do this using `twoway line` and `by()`, then Canada plots twice in the same plot window.

```
clear
set obs 100
generate year = 1990 + mod(_n, 20)
generate country = "United Kingdom" in 1/20
replace country = "United States" in 21/40
replace country = "Canada" in 41/60
replace country = "Australia" in 61/80
replace country = "New Zealand" in 81/100
generate event = (year == 1995) ///
    | ((year == 2005) & (country == "Canada"))
generate time_to_event = 0 if (event == 1)
generate outcome = runiform()

encode country, generate(countryn)
xtset countryn year
forvalue i = 1/2 {
    replace time_to_event = `i' if (l`i'.event == 1)
    replace time_to_event = -`i' if (f`i'.event == 1)
}

twoway line outcome time_to_event, ///
    by(country) name(orig, replace)
```

A manual solution adds an `occurrence` variable that numbers each event occurrence by country, then adds `occurrence` to the `by()` option.

```
generate occurrence = 1 if !missing(time_to_event)
replace occurrence = 2 if ///
    (inrange(year, 2005 - 2, 2005 + 2) & (country == "Canada"))

twoway line outcome time_to_event, ///
    by(country occurrence) name(attempt, replace)
```

This works great in the play data, but in my real data there are many more countries and many more events. I can manually code this `occurrence` variable, but that is tedious (and now I'm really curious if there's a tool or logic that works :) ).

Is there a logic to automate identifying windows? Or one that at least works with `twoway line`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have generated a variable `time_to_event` which is -2 .. 2 in a window and missing otherwise. You can use `tsspell` from SSC, installed by

```
  ssc inst tsspell
```

to label such windows. Windows are defined by spells or runs of observations all non-missing on that `time_to_event`:

```
  tsspell, cond(time_to_event < .)
```

`tsspell` requires a prior `tsset` and generates three variables explained in its help. You can then renumber windows by using one of those variables `_seq` (sequence number within spell, numbered 1 up)

```
  gen _spell2 = (_seq > 0) * sum(_seq == 1)
```

and then label spells distinctly by using `country` and the spell identifier for each spell from `_spell`, another variable produced by `tsspell`:

```
  egen gspell = group(country _spell) if _spell2, label
```

My code assumes that windows are disjoint and cannot overlap, but that seems to be one of your assumptions too. Some technique for handling spells is given by http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0029 That article does not mention `tsspell`, which in  essence is an implementation of its principles. I started explaining the principles, but the article got long enough before I could explain the program. As the help of `tsspell` is quite detailed, I doubt that a sequel paper is needed, or at least that it will be written.

(LATER) This code also assumes that windows don't touch. Solving that problem suggests a more direct approach not involving `tsspell` at all:

```
  bysort country (year) : gen w_id  = (time_to_event < .) * sum(time_to_event == -2)

  egen w_label = group(country w_id) if w_id, label
```

Comment: Thanks for the lesson! The `sum(time_to_event == -2)` trick is very helpful. I'll check out your Stata Journal article, too. Thanks.

Comment: So, can your windows overlap? Or touch?

Comment: Yes to both. I have annual events around which I define windows. The events can be in consecutive years, which creates overlapping windows. The events can also be five years apart, which creates touching windows.

Comment: I finished your article and it has all the tools I need. Thanks. As for the overlapping windows, I think I should just use the first event in a window, rather than coding a complex way to track these windows.